# Nginx configuration only matches base paths, returns 404 otherwise. Why?

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

I have a DigitalOcean droplet set-up to handle 3 websites simultaneously. Everything works exactly as it should for base paths (ex: www.johndoe.com/) but anything I add after the slash returns a 404 page (ex: www.johndoe.com/about).

Here is one of my 3 websites' config files (generated by certbot):

```
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        root /usr/share/nginx/holidayhomes7;

        server_name holidayhomes7.com www.holidayhomes7.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }

        # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/holidayhomes7.com/fullchain.pem; 

        # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/holidayhomes7.com/privkey.pem; 
    }

    server {
        if ($host = www.holidayhomes7.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot


        if ($host = holidayhomes7.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name holidayhomes7.com www.holidayhomes7.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }
```

I've tried replacing the

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

by

```
try_files $uri /path_to_html_file;
```

to no avail.

The 3 websites are node apps by the way and they all work perfectly fine on my machine's localhost.

I have no idea why this happens being a complete noob in everything regarding NGINX. I'd really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `try_files` is taking over and it never reaches the `proxy_pass` portion.

Try this in the first `server` block from your example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @app;
}

location @app {
    # depending on what OS you use, and how you've installed Nginx
    # there may be an include here to do as well, such as:
    # include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

This should attempt to find a file on the server matching the URI, and if it doesn't find one, pass the request off to NodeJS via the `proxy_pass`.

Comment: Works like a charm for non-base paths but now I get a "403 Forbidden" error on the base path.

Comment: It actually works! The 403 error I was getting was because that specific app was server-side rendered and had no index.html. It works perfectly for the others. Thanks.